# Confirmation of Proof: $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}^*, \ p = 4261 + 2308n : \text{prime} \Rightarrow p = \{a^2 + b^2 \mid \gcd(a, b) = 1\}$

Tags: prime-numbers, factoring, sums-of-squares

I developed a conjecture which I would like to confirm whether or not it holds truth for all members $n$ of the set of $\mathbb{N}^* = \mathbb{N} \ \cup \ \{0\}$.

> > $$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}^*, \ p = 4261 + 2308n : \text{prime} \Rightarrow p = \{a^2 + b^2 \mid \gcd(a, b) = 1\}$$

This statement holds truth for $n \in \{0, 1, 9, 12, 16, 25, 37, 39, 40, 42, 49, 52, 66,\ldots, 2^{232} - 1\}$. I do not know if the statement holds truth for higher values of $n$, so I attempted to prove this statement by assuming it was true.

---

**My Attempt:**

$$\begin{align} 4261 + 2308n &= a^2 + b^2 \\ \Leftrightarrow \ 4261 + 2308n - 2b^2 &= a^2 - b^2 \\ \Leftrightarrow \ 4261 + 2(34^2n - b^2) &= a^2 -
 ab + ab - b^2 \\ \Leftrightarrow \ 4261 + 2(34\sqrt n + b)(34\sqrt n -
 b) &= (a + b)(a - b)\end{align}$$  For a value $x$, if $\pi(x) = y$ and $\pi (x - 1) = y - 1$ then by definition of the function, $x$ is prime. Therefore, I need to prove that if  $\pi(\text{LHS} - 1) = \pi(\text{LHS}) - 1$, then the same applies for the $\text{RHS}$. However, I do not know what steps to do from here to achieve such a statement. Could somebody please help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An odd prime $p$ is a sum of two squares $a^2+b^2$ if and only if $p\equiv 1 \pmod 4$. This is the [Fermat's theorem on sums of two squares.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares)

Observe that the definition of your $p$ gives
$$
p=4261+2308n \equiv 1 \pmod 4
$$

Hence whenever $p$ is prime it trivially satisfies the theorem, whence you will be able to find a decomposition into sum of two squares
$$
p = a^2+b^2
$$
(Therefore the prove of the decomposition comes from the theorem and not so much from your formula. There are several proofs of the theorem [here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares))

The extra condition you have given: $\gcd(a,b)=1$ is always true since $d=\gcd(a,b)$ must divide $p$:
$$
p = a^2+b^2 \equiv 0 \pmod d
$$
and the only possibility is $d=1$. ($d\neq p$, otherwise $a^2+b^2>p$.)

Comment: Yes. I was looking at other sorts of primes being the sum of two squares, and I realised that Pythagorean primes were of that sort, for which they were one more than a multiple of $4$. Thank you very much though! I can't upvote now, for I have to wait $16$ hours, but I will definitely give you a $\ \color{green}{\checkmark}$

Comment: @user477343 That's fast! Glad to be of help.